# Binary Search and Cube roots

Tags: scheme, binary-search, square-root

Suppose we want to find the cube root of a value using binary search. We want to make a series of guesses with the binary search algorithm so that our guess become more and more precise, until they reach a close enough threshold. I'm unsure of where to start though with this problem.

```
(define (cube-root n)
    (define lo 0)
    (define hi 0)
    (define mid (/ n 2)
    ;Execute algorithm for more precise guess
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem? As long as you know how to pick `lo` and `hi` for a given number, the rest is trivial and can be implemented iteratively or recursively. You also need to decide the criteria for *good enough* solution (i.e. precision).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation, with some bits replaced with `<???>` so you can fill them in yourself:

```
(define (cube-root n)
  (define (helper lo hi)
    (define mid <???>)
    (define cube-mid <???>)
    (cond ((< (abs (- cube-mid n)) <???>) mid)
          (<???> (helper lo mid))
          (else (helper mid hi))))
  (if (negative? n)
      (helper <???> <???>)
      (helper <???> <???>)))
```

Comment: What's the difference between mid and cube-mid?

Comment: See the line after that to see what `cube-mid`'s purpose is. Note how it's being compared with `n`?